# Javascript atomic series of operations

Tags: javascript, concurrency, atomic

Given the following javascript code (or something equivalent):

```
var buf = [];
setInterval(function () {
  buf.push("token");
  // If buf has something pushed here we are screwed
  if (buf.length == 1) {
    sendCriticalLog();
  }
});

setInterval(function () {
  buf.push("other token");
});
```

Is there a way to ensure that the function of the first interval is atomic with regard to `buf`?

The only method I could come up with is:

```
function atomic(lock, cb){
  var finish = function () {
    lock.callbacks = lock.callbacks.slice(1);
    if (lock.callbacks.length) {
      lock.callbacks[0].call();
    }
  };

  cb = cb.bind(null, finish);
  if ((lock.callbacks = (lock.callbacks || []).concat([cb])).length == 1) {
    // Nothing is running
    lock.callbacks[0]();
  };
}

var buf = [];
setInterval(function () {
  atomic(buf, function () {
    buf.push("token");
    // If buf has something pushed here we are screwed
    if (buf.length == 1) {
      sendCriticalLog();
    }
  });
});

setInterval(function () {
  atomic(buf, function () {
    buf.push("other token");
  });
});
```

But that is under the assumption that `((lock.callbacks = (lock.callbacks || []).concat([cb])).length == 1)` will be guaranteed to be handled atomically. If, for example, `concat` is written in plain javascript this will probably not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is not multithreaded, so your callbacks are in fact already "atomic". buf can only be altered between calls to the callback.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought expressions were ensured to be atomic but not entire closures. Just to demonstrate: `var hello = {val: "hello"}; setTimeout(function () {hello.val = "bye";}); console.log("Hello is now", hello); while(hello.val == "hello"); console.log("Hello is now", hello);` Will freeze the repl.

Comment: @fakedrake . Hint to others.  Don't try top run that `var hello...` code in your browsers console, just to see what it does.  Total lockup.  Power off the computer for clean reset.

Comment: I think just killing the tab will do the trick for the browser... In any case I meant run it on node in which case interrupting the command should be enough.